# The definition of Determinant in the spirit of algebra and geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, determinant

The concept of *determinant* is quite unmotivational topic to introduce. Textbooks use such "strung out" introductions like axiomatic definition, Laplace expansion, Leibniz'a permutation formula or something like signed volume.

**Question**: is the following a possible way to introduce the determinant?

---

*Determinant is all about determing whether a given set of vectors are linearly independent, and a direct way to check this is to add scalar multiplications of column vectors to get the diagonal form:*

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}  & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
a_{31} & a_{32}  & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
a_{41} & a_{42}  & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
\end{pmatrix} \thicksim \begin{pmatrix} 
d_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & d_2  & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0  & d_3 & 0 \\
0 & 0  & 0 & d_4 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

*During the diagonalization process we demand that the information, i.e. the determinant, remains unchanged. Now it's clear that the vectors are linearly independent if every* $d_i$ *is nonzero, i.e.* $\prod_{i=1}^n d_i\neq0$. *It may also be the case that two columns are equal and there is no diagonal form, so we must add a condition that annihilates the determinant (this is consistent with $\prod_{i=1}^n d_i=0$), since column vectors can't be linearly independent.*

*If we want to have a real valued function that provides this information, then we simply introduce an ad hoc function* $\det:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ *with following properties:*

1. $$\det (a_1,\ldots,a_i,\ldots,a_j,\ldots,a_n)=\det (a_1,\ldots,a_i,\ldots,k\cdot a_i+a_j,\ldots,a_n).$$
2. $$\det(d_1\cdot e_1,\ldots,d_n\cdot e_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n d_i.$$
3. $$\det (a_1,\ldots,a_i,\ldots,a_j,\ldots,a_n)=0, \space \space \text{if} \space \space a_i=a_j.$$

---

From the previous definition of determinant we can infer the **multilinearity** property:

$$[a_1,\ldots,c_1 \cdot u+c_2 \cdot v,\ldots,a_n]\thicksim diag[d_1,\ldots,c_1 \cdot d'_i+c_2 \cdot d''_i ,\ldots,d_n],$$ so $$\det[a_1,\ldots,c_1 \cdot u+c_2 \cdot v,\ldots,a_n]=\prod_{j=1:j\neq i}^n d_j(c_1 \cdot d'_i+c_2 \cdot d''_i)$$ $$=c_1\det(diag[d_1,\ldots, d'_i,\ldots,d_n])+c_2\det(diag[d_1,\ldots, d''_i,\ldots,d_n])$$ $$=c_1\det[a_1,\ldots,u,\ldots,a_n]+c_2\det[a_1,\ldots, v,\ldots,a_n].$$

Note that previous multilinearity together with property $(1)$ gives the property $(2)$, so we know from the literature that the determinant function $\det:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ actually exists and it is unique.

---

Obviously, the determinant offers information how orthogonal a set of vectors is. Thus, with Gram-Schmidt process we can form an orthogonal set of vectors form set $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$, and by multilinearity and property $(2)$ the absolute value of determinant is the volume of parallelepiped spanned by the set of vectors.

**Definition**.
Volume of parallelepiped formed by set of vectors $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ is $Vol(a_1,\ldots, a_n)=Vol(a_1,\ldots, a_{n-1})\cdot |a_{n}^{\bot}|=|a_{1}^{\bot}|\cdots |a_{n}^{\bot}|$, where $a_{i}^{\bot} \bot span(a_1,\ldots, a_{i-1}).$

---

This approach to determinant works equally well if we begin with the volume of a parallelepiped (geometric approach) or with the search of invertibility (algebraic approach). I was motivated by the book *Linear algebra and its applications* by Lax on chapter 5:

*Rather than start with a formula for the determinant, we shall deduce it from the properties forced on it by the geometric properties of signed volume. This approach to determinants is due to E. Artin.*

1. $\det (a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0$, if $a_i=a_j$, $i\neq j.$
2. $\det (a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is a multilinear function of its arguments, in the sense that if all $a_i, i \neq j$ are fixed, $\det$ is a linear function of the remaining argument $a_j.$
3. $\det(e_1,\ldots,e_n)=1.$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98825/discussion-on-question-by-hulkster-the-definition-of-determinant-in-the-spirit-o).

Answer (score 9):

That seems quite opaque: It's a way of computing a quantity rather than telling what exactly it is or even motivating it. It also leaves completely open the question of why such a function exists and is well-defined. The properties you give are sufficient if you're trying to put a matrix in upper-triangular form, but what about other computations? It also gives no justification for one of the most important properties of the determinant, that $\det(ab) = \det a \det b$.

I think the best way to define the determinant is to introduce the wedge product $\Lambda^* V$ of a finite-dimensional space $V$. Given that, any map $f:V \to V$ induces a map $\bar{f}:\Lambda^n V \to \Lambda^n V$, where $n = \dim V$. But $\Lambda^n V$ is a $1$-dimensional space, so $\bar{f}$ is just multiplication by a scalar (independent of a choice of basis); that scalar is by definition exactly $\det f$. Then, for example, we get the condition that $\det f\not = 0$ iff $f$ is an isomorphism for free: For a basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ of $V$, we have $\det f\not = 0$ iff $f(v_1\wedge \cdots \wedge v_n) = f(v_1) \wedge \cdots \wedge f(v_n) \not = 0$; that is, iff the $f(v_i)$ are linearly independent. Furthermore, since $h = fg$ has $\bar{h} = \bar{f}\bar{g}$, we have $\det(fg) = \det f \det g$. The other properties follow similarly. It requires a bit more sophistication than is usually assumed in a linear algebra class, but it's the first construction of $\det$ I've seen that's motivated and transparently explains what's otherwise a list of arbitrary properties.

Comment: I beg to disagree. This is arguably the most *refined*, the most *elegant* or even the most *useful* definition of determinant, but I think this is also the **least** motivated definition. Why on earth is there any need to introduce exterior algebra in order to define the volume of a parallelepiped or the proportional change in volume due to the application of a linear map? How can one see the merits of such a definition at the outset? Motivation-wise, this definition makes no sense at all.

Comment: The motivation is the idea that $\det f = 0$ is equivalent to singularity, which is much more interesting and important that computing the volume of a parallelepiped (and still makes sense over a field $k\not = \mathbb{R}$). The volume form on a space on general manifold is defined in terms of the same exterior product, so it follows automatically. (This requires more analysis than is usually assumed in an introductory class, but it's not like computing the volume of a parallelepiped in arbitrary dimensions is really a compelling or interesting motivation anyway.)

Comment: ...also, in the volume definition, you're still stuck showing that the determinant has the laundry list of properties in the OP, which is not immediate. If you assume that $\det$ is well-defined and invariant under conjugation (or similar behavior), then you can interpret $\det g$ for $g$ upper-triangular as the volume of a parallelepiped and proceed from there. But there's not an obvious way of showing the geometric meaning of $\det$ for an arbitrary matrix, and it's not clear from the given three conditions why $\det$ should be multiplicative, one of its most important properties.

Comment: I think we are not on the same page about the meaning of the word "motivation". You seem to be talking about whether a certain goal is worth pursuing, but in the context of the OP and my previous comment, we are talking about whether it's convincing at the outset that a certain definition or a certain setup would lead us to our desired goal. In this sense the use of exterior algebra is rather unmotivated.

Comment: As Paul Halmos put it (on p.53, *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*): "The reader might well charge that the discussion was not very strongly motivated. The complete motivation cannot be contained in this book; the justification for studying multilinear algebra is the wide applicability of the subject. The only application that we shall make is to the theory of determinants (which, to be sure, could be treated by more direct but less elegant methods, involving much greater dependence on arbitrary choices of bases)".

Comment: @Juho: Well, sure: If you define the determinant for upper triangular or diagonal matrices and reduce to that case, then multiplicativity follows easily (if not actually organically). The point is that you're assuming that the three properties you give uniquely and completely determine the value of the determinant, which is not obvious. It's also less of a definition of the determinant than an algorithm for computing it; that's not necessarily a problem, but it's at least not a great motivation.

Answer (score 3):

The way I teach determinants to my students is to start with the case $n=2$, and to use the complex numbers and/or trigonometry in order to show that, for $(a,b), (c,d)$ vectors on the plane, the quantity
$$ad-bc=||(a,b)||\cdotp ||(c,d)|| \sin \theta$$
is the signed area between $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ (in this order).

Then, using the vector product and its properties (we have seen it before coming to the topic of determinants in full generality), we check that $3$ by $3$ determinants carry the meaning of signed volumes.

The next step is to introduce determinants as alternate multilinear functions.  We have seen examples of bilinear maps (inner products), trilinear maps, such as
$$(u,v,w)\mapsto (u\times v)\bullet w$$
and the quadrilinear maps $$(a,b,c,d)\mapsto (a\bullet c) (b\bullet d)-(b\bullet c) (a\bullet d),$$
$$(a,b,c,d)\mapsto (a \times b)\bullet (c\times d).$$

Now, when explaining multilinearity we did emphasise that the fact that the last two examples are equal can be proven if only we check equality for the case where $a,b,c,d$ are vectors of the canonical basis.

Then the time comes to define the determinant of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is a new example of $n-$linear, alternate function. They check that the vector space of such maps is indeed $\left(^n_n\right).$  The students thus learn that the determinant is essentially the only possible such function, up to a multiple, in the same way they saw that more general multilinear maps depend exclusively on their values on vectors of a chosen basis (say, the canonical basis in our case).

Although I learnt to prove stuff such as $\det(AB)=\det(A) \det(B)$ by strict functoriality, in class we do define the map
$$L(X_1, \ldots , X_n)=\det(AX_1, \ldots , AX_n),$$ which by uniqueness is a constant multiple of the determinant function $T(X_1, \ldots , X_n)=\det(X_1, \ldots, X_n),$ and compute the constant by evaluating on the identity matrix, i.e. $X_i=e_i.$

Thus $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B).$

It is in T.W. Korner's book called *Vectors, Pure and Applied* that one can see a construction that uses elementary matrices and is rigorous.  The OP can check Korner's book to see a nice, slightly more down-to-earth exposition.

In op. cit. one can see how Korner uses the fact that an invertible matrix can be decomposed as a product of elementary matrices to obtain the formula $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B).$

**Note:**  I have been deliberately brief in my exposition, just so as not to repeat too much stuff that was already included in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

$\det$ is the only multilinear alternating linear map such that $\det I = 1$. (2) and (3) combined with the following property would define $\det$ uniquely.
$$ \det(a_1,\dots,u,\dots,a_n) + \det(a_1,\dots,\lambda v,\dots,a_n) = \det(a_1,\dots,u + \lambda v,\dots,a_n)
$$
The only thing missing from your definition is linearity.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you belive that it's impossible to derive multilinearity from propetries $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$?

Comment: @Juho Yes, but it is difficult to prove.

Comment: But if the properties $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ give correct determinant for every matrix, then isn't the multilinearity an automatic additional property?

Comment: @Juho The current definition of $\det$ satisfy (1),(2) and (3), but there is no guarantee that no other nonlinear function also satisfy them.

Comment: @Juho I think your definition is *equivalent* to Artin's, but Artin's definition makes the proofs of several properties of the determinant much easier.

Comment: @user1551 True. In my definition I find the volume using Gram-Schmidt process. Assuming multilinearity as axiom takes some geometric resoning, but still it's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The geometric meaning of the determinant of, say, a 3 by 3 matrix is the (signed) volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the three column vectors (alternatively the three row vectors).  This generalizes the (signed) area of the parallelogram spanned by the two column vectors of a 2 by 2 matrix.

At the next stage, to pursue the geometric definition you would have to clarify the meaning of "signed" above.  The naive definition of volume is always positive whereas the determinant could be negative, so there is some explaining to do in terms of orientations.

The route most often chosen both by instructors and textbook writers is the algebraic one where one can write down a magic formula and, boom! the determinant has been defined.  This is fine if you want to get through a certain amount of material required by the course, but pedagogically this may not be the best approach.

Ultimately a combination of the geometry and the algebra is required to explain this concept properly.  It connects to more advanced topics like exterior algebras but that's the next stage already.

Answer (score -1):

A rationale i could give to the determinant function is to generalise the property of the power, i.e we know that for any scalars $x,a,b,c$ it holds: 
$x^{a + b + c \ldots} = x^a x^b x^c\ldots$

But, lets assume that $a,b,c\ldots$ are actually the diagonal entries of a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ then it holds that $x^{trace(\mathbf{A})} = det(x^\mathbf{A})$ , with $x^A$ the matrix exponential (of base $x$);

Comment: what is the matrix power?